How to assign colors and shape for variables in fviz_pca_biplot
I am plotting the PCA using FVIZ_PCA_BIPLOT. My (temp) database has 55 groups, 4250 observations and 19 variables. An example of my df is:
temp <- data.frame(ind = c(AZ34, B546, C234, AC765, B498, AW345), 
        group = c("A",  "B", "C", "B", "B", "A"),
        X1 = c(13.953, 12.392, 13.378, 9.111,  8.391, 10.528), 
        X2 = c(1.19, 1.296, 1.072, 1.1, 1.076, 1.148), 
        X3 = c(25.713, 25.908, 25.021, 25.081, 26.538, 30.567),
        X4 = c(0.136,  0.142, 0.137, 0.158, 0.15, 0.168), 
        X5 = c(1.052, 1.059, 0.893, 0.9, 0.942, 0.99), 
        X6 = c(0.023, 0.02, 0.425, 0.027, 0.018,0.038))

I have created a file to assign colours and shape for each "group". The file looks like this:
   file <- data.frame(ind = c("AZ34", "B546", "C234", "AC765", "B498", "AW345"), 
                       group = c("A",  "B", "C", "B", "B", "A"),
                       shape = c("green", "blue", "red", "blue","blue", "green"), 
                       colour = c(1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 8))

The code that I used to plot the PCA was:
fviz_pca_biplot(temp.pca,
                label = "var",
                col.ind = file$colour,
                col.var = "black",
                habillage = temp$group)

But, they don't work. I need the individuals and groups to have the colour and shape I decided in the file, and I need the VAR1...6 to be plotted, also. I've tried the following code (How to assign colors for variables in "fviz_pca_biplot" from the R package "factoextra"?) as well, but it doesn't work either way
Any suggestion?
Thanks
